# Не работает мьют. Роли выдаются, но сообщения не удаляются. В интерпретаторе ошибок нету

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Не работает именно часть с @bot.event

### Код:

---

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True, ban_members=True, kick_members=True)
async def mute(ctx, user: discord.Member, time: int, reason):
    role = user.guild.get_role(787992576166199306) # айди роли которую будет получать юзер
    await ctx.send(f'{user} получил мут на {time} минут по причине: {reason}')
    await user.add_roles(role)
    await user.move_to(None)
    await asyncio.sleep(time * 60)
    await user.remove_roles(role)
    global mute=discord.utils.get(guild.roles,name="mute")
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if mute:
        await message.delete()
    else:
        return
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if mute:
        await message.delete()
```

У вас пользователь на наличие "мута" не проверяется.
Проверяйте участника на наличие роли - "**mute**"